# How do I enable jQuery validator while disabling the default post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, jquery-validate

We have a form that loads in an overlay window. Instead of the default form post, we use a jQuery `$.post` to post via ajax so that we stay on the current page with the overlay window open. So the code is something like this:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('myPage.cfm', $('#myForm').serialize()); 
});
```

This prevents the default post and posts via ajax instead.

We are also validating the form with the jQuery validate plugin. So this is the validate code:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        numUnits: "number",
        pctBusiness: {
            number: true,
            range: [0, 100] 
        }
    }   
});
```

The problem is that while the validate plugin is validating the proper fields on focus out, the preventDefault code and programmatic ajax post is stopping it from preventing submit when fields are invalid. How can I keep my ajax post, but still enable the validation?

Comment: As per [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), the `submitHandler` callback function is the _"right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `valid()` function to check whether the form is valid, only then post the form data

```
$('#submitForm').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#myForm').valid()){
        $.post('myPage.cfm', $('#myForm').serialize());
    }
});
```

another option is to use the submit handler

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            numUnits: "number",
            pctBusiness: {
                number: true,
                range: [0, 100]
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            //do the submit here
            alert('test');
            //$.post('myPage.cfm', $('#myForm').serialize());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, both of these options look clear and logical. I'll try them. Question - why is it that preventDefault of submit would not stop validation from occurring but of the click would? Does the validation execute before the submit is invoked?

Comment: @froadie the validation framework validates the form on the submit handler... when you prevent the submit buttons click teh submit event is never fired so the validation does not happen

Comment: I changed it to a submit and now I'm getting very strange behavior; if I enter something non-numeric in either field, the submit is prevented - but if I enter something out of range for the pctBusiness field, even though the error pops up next to the field, it still submits.

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate it exactly, but see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LWky3/2/ - it validates the fields when focus is lost, but when you submit it still hits the `alert('test')` statement

Comment: @froadie sorry... that was a wrong way... you need to use the submit handler... see the update http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LWky3/4/

Comment: As per [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), the `submitHandler` callback function is the _"right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated"_; not a custom `click` handler.  Why not edit this answer to reflect that?

Comment: sorry for the sporadic updating... this is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use Ajaxform

```
 $("#myForm").ajaxForm({ 
               success:  function (response, statusText, xhr, $form)
                 {// do validation here and  success msg
             },
       beforeSend: function(xhr){},
       complete: function(){},
       dataType:  'json'
       });
```

Comment: -1 for not answering the question.  Any ajax would go inside of the validation plugin's `submitHandler` callback function, not the other way around.

Comment: set some message parameter from server scripting side then check in success parameter. in this validation done from server side